# wcf endpoint address mock

Tags: c#, wcf, mocking

for our acceptance test, we've created mock implementations for the 3rd party services and the way it works is we substitute the endpoint addresses for those services before each test is run:

```
var webConfigPath = @"..\..\..\..\Hosts\Host\web.config";
var mockSvcUri = "http://localhost:8000/AcceptanceTest/VehicleService";

protected override void before_all()
{
    var mockVehicleService = Mock.Of<IVehicleService>();
    Mock.Get(mockVehicleService).Setup(c => {...} ));

    var serviceHost = mockVehicleService.GenerateMockServiceHost(new Uri(mockSvcUri));
    var previousEndPoint = serviceHost.UpdateClientEndpoint(webConfigPath);
    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

...and change them back to original addresses in the `after_all()`. This isn't ideal because `after_all()` may not execute if the test falls over we'd end up with the incorrect configuration file.

I was wondering whether it is possible to create an Interface and class for reading the config and make the WCF service to read the endpoint addresses via this interface, instead of the `web.config` file directly. This way it would be easy to mock out the endpoint addresses for tests. Or perhaps there is another solution?